# Seemingly can't use new libraries in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, libraries

I've been trying to make use of numerous libraries for my react native project for android, but none seem to be working. As an example, I tried to import and use the "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" library. It installs fine and shows up in my dependencies, but an attempt to use it results in the error "NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null."

I get this or similar errors every time I try to use a new library. I really am clueless here, so any help is appreciated.

To clarify, this is a issue that seemingly just manifested out of nowhere. Up until now, I have had zero issue importing and using libraries, and my project is currently using multiple libraries without issue.

I tried resetting the cache and rebuilding the project as recommended, but as far as I can tell, these steps have changed nothing.